# How to determine the number of days a user has used an app using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to determine the number of days a user has used an iOS app. I want to trigger an amplitude event the first to fourth days but not after the fourth day he uses it. How can I track how many days the user used the app?

Comment: You can always store & update the active time of the user using the app. The logic should be quite simple.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using UserDefaults to count how many times users open the app:

```
var userOpenApp: Int {
    get {
        UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "UserOpenApp")
    }
    set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "UserOpenApp")
    }
}
```

then check the number in sceneDelegate or appDelegate, and update it:

```
userOpenApp // check the number
userOpenApp = userOpenApp + 1 // update the number
```

Comment: You will need to store the dates too, to be sure you don’t add twice the same days.

Answer (score 0):

Store the needed data in UserDefaults and call it when you need to do the calculation.